# Not Novel and Obvious

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [WO2014165349A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014165349A1)

How is this patentable? Where is the inventive step? This reminds me of Molecular Pathology vs. Myriad Genetics.